# Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: - Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes

We have upgraded our Kubernates Service cluster on Azure to latest version 1.12.4. After that we suddenly  recognize that pods and nodes cannot communicate between anymore by private ip :

```
kubectl get pods -o wide -n kube-system -l component=kube-proxy
NAME               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE       IP           NODE
kube-proxy-bfhbw   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.4     aks-agentpool-16086733-1
kube-proxy-d7fj9   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.35    aks-agentpool-16086733-0
kube-proxy-j24th   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.97    aks-agentpool-16086733-3
kube-proxy-x7ffx   1/1       Running   2          16h       10.0.4.128   aks-agentpool-16086733-4
```

As you see the node aks-agentpool-16086733-0 has private IP 10.0.4.35 . When we try to check logs on pods which are on this node we got such error:
Get https://aks-agentpool-16086733-0:10250/containerLogs/emw-sit/nginx-sit-deploy-864b7d7588-bw966/nginx-sit?tailLines=5000&timestamps=true: dial tcp 10.0.4.35:10250: i/o timeout

We got the Tiller ( Helm) on this node as well, and if try to connect to tiller we got such error from Client PC:

```
shmits-imac:~ andris.shmits01$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.12.3", GitCommit:"eecf22f77df5f65c823aacd2dbd30ae6c65f186e", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Error: forwarding ports: error upgrading connection: error dialing backend: dial tcp 10.0.4.35:10250: i/o timeout
```

Does anybody have any idea why the pods and nodes lost connectivity by private IP ?

Comment: Crossposting is not allowed on the [SE] network. Please delete one of the posts.

Answer (score 1):

Please check if the Cluster ControlPlane SecurityGroup value is same as before and after the upgrade. The change in security group will cause communication issue between the controlplane and the pods.